# Update null values in a column based on non null values percentage of the column

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, pgadmin

I need to update the null values of a column in a table for each category based on the percentage of the non-null values. The following table shows the null values for a particular category -

[image]

There are only two types of values in the column. The percentage of types based on rows is -
[image]

The number of rows with null values is 7, I need to randomly populate the null values based on the percentage share of the non-null values as shown below -  *38%(CV) of 7 = 3, 63%(NCV) of 7 = 4*

[image]

Comment: it is postgres.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dynamically calculate the "NULL rate", one way to do it could be:

```sql
with pcts as (
  select 
    (select count(*)::numeric from the_table where type = 'cv') / (select count(*) from the_table where type is not null) as cv_pct,
    (select count(*)::numeric from the_table where type = 'ncv') / (select count(*) from the_table where type is not null) as ncv_pct,
    (select count(*) from the_table where type is null) as null_count
), calc as (
  select d.ctid, 
         p.cv_pct, 
         p.ncv_pct, 
         row_number() over () as rn, 
         case 
           when row_number() over () <= round(null_count * p.cv_pct) then 'cv'
           else 'ncv'
         end as new_type
  from the_table d
    cross join pcts p
  where type is null
)
update the_table t
  set type = c.new_type
from calc c
where t.ctid = c.ctid
```

The first [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) calculates the percentage of each type and the total number of NULL values (in theory the percentage of the NCV type isn't really needed, but I included it for completeness)

The second then calculates for each row which new type should be used. This is done by multiplying the "current" row number with the expected percentage (the CASE expression)

This is then used to update the target table. I have used the `ctid` as an alternative for a primary key, because your sample data does not have any unique column (or combination of columns). If you do have a primary key that you haven't shown, replace `ctid` with that primary key column.

I wouldn't be surprised though, if there was a shorter, more efficient way to do it, but for now I can't think of a better alternative.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e2b5ba44aefe86bb44e343b77e6f6a1f)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on PG11 or later, you can use the `groups` frame to do this in what should be close to a single pass (except reordering for output when sorted by `tid`) with window functions:

```
select tid, category, id, type, 
       case 
         when type is not null then type
         when round(
                (count(*) over (partition by category
                                  order by type nulls last
                         groups between 2 preceding
                                    and 2 preceding))::numeric / 
                coalesce(
                  nullif(
                    count(*) over (partition by category
                                       order by type nulls last
                                      groups 2 preceding 
                                     exclude group), 0), 1
                ) * 
                count(*) over (partition by category
                                   order by type nulls last
                                  groups current row) 
              ) >= row_number() over (partition by category, type
                                          order by tid) 
              then
                first_value(type) over (partition by category
                                            order by type nulls last
                                   groups between 2 preceding
                                              and 2 preceding)
              else
                first_value(type) over (partition by category
                                            order by type nulls last
                                           groups 1 preceding
                                           exclude group)
        end as extended_type
  from cv_ncv 
 order by tid;
```

[Working fiddle here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4187d68991b171df1f3855e01ed6a3ca)